# AVFoundation, how to show subtitiles?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset

I'm developing a video editing tool for mac os, using cocoa and avfoundation

a video file is used by NSAsset object, the asset have video tracks, audio and (as mentioned in apple docs) subtitles!!

I can play with the video and audios tracks, but what about the subtitles???
does it has to be a subtitles track attached in the video file?? where I can find a one??

I want be able to show subtitles from separated file, like srt and other formats??
does avfoundation have any thing to do in this case, or I'm supposed to implement it myself and show/hide subtitles in another layer??

Answer (score 2):

AVFoundation supports closed caption tracks. I don't know whether it supports subtitle tracks. Either way, they have to be part of the asset, not a separate file.

If you want to support SRT files, you need to do that yourself. Boundary time observers will help, but beware of slop: the player may call an observer block early, late, or not at all (coalescing).

If you're making an editor that uses AVComposition, you *may* be able to create a subtitle track and populate it with the information from the SRT file. I have not looked into this.